# Execute only parts of code that is injected as a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, performance, dom

I am using Blockly, and the below code is injected via a string variable into a document. The string (code) is generated automatically:

```
var cv; //global variable will execute since used inside onGreenFlagClicked

// will get execute
function helloWorld() {
  MinecraftAvatar.waveHelloForNSeconds(7)
}

function onGreenFlagClicked() {
  cv = helloWorld();
  MinecraftAvatar.sayForNSeconds("I am Mike", 7)

};

Players.walkForwardForNSeconds(7) // no execution
MinecraftAvatar.waveHelloForNSeconds(7) // no execution
```

In the above string (code) I want to execute `onGreenFlagClicked()` when the script is appended to the DOM. My problem is that I only want to execute parts of that code, e.g: variables, the function definitions, but not the other things like shown above.

I want to disable

```
Players.walkForwardForNSeconds(7) // no execution
MinecraftAvatar.waveHelloForNSeconds(7) // no execution
```

...when the code is appended to DOM.

Is this possible by any chance?

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in an IIFE that takes an array of the function names that you want to execute. Then iterate that array to call the functions from inside.

Comment: If you don't want to execute `Players.walkForwardForNSeconds(7)` when the script loads, then why is it there? *When* do you want to have it executed then?

Comment: i am using google blockly , so when i drag a block that code gets automatically generated and a kid can do that too, so i want to avoid that

Comment: This information should be in the question. It is currently not stated in your question that this code is in fact *injected* into a document and coming from somewhere else (blocky). That seems like critical information in order to correctly understand the question...

Comment: okay i will add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to execute the following:

```
Players.walkForwardForNSeconds(7) // no execution 
MinecraftAvatar.waveHelloForNSeconds(7) // no execution
```

...then you would need to remove those lines.

It is not nice to have to manipulate a string with code, but you could for instance remove all code that follows the last occurrence of a `}`, like this:

```
code = code.replace(/[^}]*$/, "");
```

Alternatively, you could remove all lines that start with a capital letter (without preceding spaces):

```
code = code.replace(/^[A-Z].*/gm, "");
```

To *add* a call, you can just append to the code:

```
code = code + "\nonGreenFlagClicked();";
```

Comment: ```appendScript({ text: code }, aframeWindow.document, () => {
      aframeWindow.onGreenFlagClicked();
    }) ```    i am appending the code, but you're telling me to remove those two lines by parsing it(may be regex?) because i would also have  **var something** in global scope outside ```onGreenFlagClicked()``` and i need to filter that along with those two lines, if the var is inside the green flag function.
 Some guy said i should put my code in IIFE and pass the function as params and loop over it to execute that function, what's better ?

Comment: Is the `code` variable not created by you then? If not, then this poses a security risk: why would you trust `code`?

Comment: hey i have updated the question, it's being generated by blocks

Comment: hey can you upvote this question , idk why but they are saying to improve existing question to ask a new question  , please help , i'll promise i will make my questions clearer , 
@trincot